# Building qt module from source for iOS doesn't apply changes

Tags: ios, xcode, qt, qml, qt5

I'm having some trouble building qt module from source.

A while ago I had a question on how to compile a qt module from source and it worked perfectly, however the same procedure doesn't seem to work anymore.

Since I have to add some code to enable DRM for media-player on iOS I edit `qtmultimedia/src/plugins/avfoundation/mediaplayer/avfmediaplayersession.mm` as that's the part responsible for playback of multimedia for iOS.

But after running `qmake`, `make`, `make install` the module works the same as before, almost as using some cashed version of it and completely ignoring anything I do to the source code.

This is the makefile generated by `qmake` (I removed some lines as it's too long, but wanted for the paths to be visible in case I miss something there)

```
#############################################################################
# Makefile for building: qtmultimedia
# Generated by qmake (3.1) (Qt 5.11.3)
# Project:  /Users/user/QTProjects/qtmultimedia/qtmultimedia.pro
# Template: subdirs
# Command: /Users/user/Qt/5.11.3/ios/bin/qmake -o Makefile /Users/user/QTProjects/qtmultimedia/qtmultimedia.pro
#############################################################################

MAKEFILE      = Makefile

first: make_first
QMAKE         = /Users/user/Qt/5.11.3/ios/bin/qmake
DEL_FILE      = rm -f
CHK_DIR_EXISTS= test -d
MKDIR         = mkdir -p
COPY          = cp -f
COPY_FILE     = cp -f
COPY_DIR      = cp -f -R
INSTALL_FILE  = install -m 644 -p
INSTALL_PROGRAM = install -m 755 -p
INSTALL_DIR   = cp -f -R
QINSTALL      = /Users/user/Qt/5.11.3/ios/bin/qmake -install qinstall
QINSTALL_PROGRAM = /Users/user/Qt/5.11.3/ios/bin/qmake -install qinstall -exe
DEL_FILE      = rm -f
SYMLINK       = ln -f -s
DEL_DIR       = rmdir
MOVE          = mv -f
TAR           = tar -cf
COMPRESS      = gzip -9f
DISTNAME      = qtmultimedia1.0.0
DISTDIR = /Users/user/QTProjects/buildqtm/.obj/qtmultimedia1.0.0
SUBTARGETS    =  \
        sub-src \
        sub-examples \
        sub-tests


####### Custom Variables
EXPORT_VALID_ARCHS = arm64 x86_64
EXPORT_ACTIVE_ARCHS = $(filter $(EXPORT_VALID_ARCHS), $(ARCHS))
EXPORT_ARCH_ARGS = $(foreach arch, $(if $(EXPORT_ACTIVE_ARCHS), $(EXPORT_ACTIVE_ARCHS), $(EXPORT_VALID_ARCHS)), -arch $(arch))
EXPORT_QMAKE_XARCH_CFLAGS = $(EXPORT_QMAKE_XARCH_CFLAGS_arm64) $(EXPORT_QMAKE_XARCH_CFLAGS_x86_64)
EXPORT_QMAKE_XARCH_LFLAGS = $(EXPORT_QMAKE_XARCH_LFLAGS_arm64) $(EXPORT_QMAKE_XARCH_LFLAGS_x86_64)
EXPORT_QMAKE_XARCH_CFLAGS_arm64 = -Xarch_arm64 -miphoneos-version-min=10.0 -Xarch_arm64 -isysroot/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS12.0.sdk
EXPORT_QMAKE_XARCH_LFLAGS_arm64 = -Xarch_arm64 -miphoneos-version-min=10.0 -Xarch_arm64 -Wl,-syslibroot,/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS12.0.sdk
EXPORT_QMAKE_XARCH_CFLAGS_x86_64 = -Xarch_x86_64 -mios-simulator-version-min=10.0 -Xarch_x86_64 -isysroot/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator12.0.sdk
EXPORT_QMAKE_XARCH_LFLAGS_x86_64 = -Xarch_x86_64 -mios-simulator-version-min=10.0 -Xarch_x86_64 -Wl,-syslibroot,/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator12.0.sdk

sub-src-qmake_all:  FORCE
    @test -d src/ || mkdir -p src/
    cd src/ && $(QMAKE) -o Makefile /Users/user/QTProjects/qtmultimedia/src/src.pro
    cd src/ && $(MAKE) -f Makefile qmake_all
sub-src: FORCE
    @test -d src/ || mkdir -p src/
    cd src/ && ( test -e Makefile || $(QMAKE) -o Makefile /Users/user/QTProjects/qtmultimedia/src/src.pro ) && $(MAKE) -f Makefile
sub-src-make_first: FORCE
    @test -d src/ || mkdir -p src/
    cd src/ && ( test -e Makefile || $(QMAKE) -o Makefile /Users/user/QTProjects/qtmultimedia/src/src.pro ) && $(MAKE) -f Makefile 
sub-src-all: FORCE
    @test -d src/ || mkdir -p src/
    cd src/ && ( test -e Makefile || $(QMAKE) -o Makefile /Users/user/QTProjects/qtmultimedia/src/src.pro ) && $(MAKE) -f Makefile all
sub-src-clean: FORCE
    @test -d src/ || mkdir -p src/
    cd src/ && ( test -e Makefile || $(QMAKE) -o Makefile /Users/user/QTProjects/qtmultimedia/src/src.pro ) && $(MAKE) -f Makefile clean
sub-src-distclean: FORCE
    @test -d src/ || mkdir -p src/
    cd src/ && ( test -e Makefile || $(QMAKE) -o Makefile /Users/user/QTProjects/qtmultimedia/src/src.pro ) && $(MAKE) -f Makefile distclean
sub-src-install_subtargets: FORCE
    @test -d src/ || mkdir -p src/
    cd src/ && ( test -e Makefile || $(QMAKE) -o Makefile /Users/user/QTProjects/qtmultimedia/src/src.pro ) && $(MAKE) -f Makefile install
sub-src-uninstall_subtargets: FORCE
    @test -d src/ || mkdir -p src/
    cd src/ && ( test -e Makefile || $(QMAKE) -o Makefile /Users/user/QTProjects/qtmultimedia/src/src.pro ) && $(MAKE) -f Makefile uninstall
sub-examples-qmake_all: sub-src-qmake_all FORCE
    @test -d examples/ || mkdir -p examples/
    cd examples/ && $(QMAKE) -o Makefile /Users/user/QTProjects/qtmultimedia/examples/examples.pro
    cd examples/ && $(MAKE) -f Makefile qmake_all
sub-examples: sub-src FORCE
    @test -d examples/ || mkdir -p examples/
    cd examples/ && ( test -e Makefile || $(QMAKE) -o Makefile /Users/user/QTProjects/qtmultimedia/examples/examples.pro ) && $(MAKE) -f Makefile
sub-examples-make_first: sub-src-make_first FORCE
    @test -d examples/ || mkdir -p examples/
    cd examples/ && ( test -e Makefile || $(QMAKE) -o Makefile /Users/user/QTProjects/qtmultimedia/examples/examples.pro ) && $(MAKE) -f Makefile 
sub-examples-all: sub-src-all FORCE
    @test -d examples/ || mkdir -p examples/
    cd examples/ && ( test -e Makefile || $(QMAKE) -o Makefile /Users/user/QTProjects/qtmultimedia/examples/examples.pro ) && $(MAKE) -f Makefile all
sub-examples-clean: sub-src-clean FORCE
    @test -d examples/ || mkdir -p examples/
    cd examples/ && ( test -e Makefile || $(QMAKE) -o Makefile /Users/user/QTProjects/qtmultimedia/examples/examples.pro ) && $(MAKE) -f Makefile clean
sub-examples-distclean: sub-src-distclean FORCE
    @test -d examples/ || mkdir -p examples/
    cd examples/ && ( test -e Makefile || $(QMAKE) -o Makefile /Users/user/QTProjects/qtmultimedia/examples/examples.pro ) && $(MAKE) -f Makefile distclean
sub-examples-install_subtargets: sub-src-install_subtargets FORCE
    @test -d examples/ || mkdir -p examples/
    cd examples/ && ( test -e Makefile || $(QMAKE) -o Makefile /Users/user/QTProjects/qtmultimedia/examples/examples.pro ) && $(MAKE) -f Makefile install
sub-examples-uninstall_subtargets: sub-src-uninstall_subtargets FORCE
    @test -d examples/ || mkdir -p examples/
    cd examples/ && ( test -e Makefile || $(QMAKE) -o Makefile /Users/user/QTProjects/qtmultimedia/examples/examples.pro ) && $(MAKE) -f Makefile uninstall
sub-tests-qmake_all: sub-src-qmake_all FORCE
    @test -d tests/ || mkdir -p tests/
    cd tests/ && $(QMAKE) -o Makefile /Users/user/QTProjects/qtmultimedia/tests/tests.pro
    cd tests/ && $(MAKE) -f Makefile qmake_all
sub-tests: sub-src FORCE
    @test -d tests/ || mkdir -p tests/
    cd tests/ && ( test -e Makefile || $(QMAKE) -o Makefile /Users/user/QTProjects/qtmultimedia/tests/tests.pro ) && $(MAKE) -f Makefile
sub-tests-make_first: sub-src-make_first FORCE
    @test -d tests/ || mkdir -p tests/
    cd tests/ && ( test -e Makefile || $(QMAKE) -o Makefile /Users/user/QTProjects/qtmultimedia/tests/tests.pro ) && $(MAKE) -f Makefile 
sub-tests-all: sub-src-all FORCE
    @test -d tests/ || mkdir -p tests/
    cd tests/ && ( test -e Makefile || $(QMAKE) -o Makefile /Users/user/QTProjects/qtmultimedia/tests/tests.pro ) && $(MAKE) -f Makefile all
sub-tests-clean: sub-src-clean FORCE
    @test -d tests/ || mkdir -p tests/
    cd tests/ && ( test -e Makefile || $(QMAKE) -o Makefile /Users/user/QTProjects/qtmultimedia/tests/tests.pro ) && $(MAKE) -f Makefile clean
sub-tests-distclean: sub-src-distclean FORCE
    @test -d tests/ || mkdir -p tests/
    cd tests/ && ( test -e Makefile || $(QMAKE) -o Makefile /Users/user/QTProjects/qtmultimedia/tests/tests.pro ) && $(MAKE) -f Makefile distclean
sub-tests-install_subtargets: sub-src-install_subtargets FORCE
    @test -d tests/ || mkdir -p tests/
    cd tests/ && ( test -e Makefile || $(QMAKE) -o Makefile /Users/user/QTProjects/qtmultimedia/tests/tests.pro ) && $(MAKE) -f Makefile install
sub-tests-uninstall_subtargets: sub-src-uninstall_subtargets FORCE
    @test -d tests/ || mkdir -p tests/
    cd tests/ && ( test -e Makefile || $(QMAKE) -o Makefile /Users/user/QTProjects/qtmultimedia/tests/tests.pro ) && $(MAKE) -f Makefile uninstall

Makefile: /Users/user/QTProjects/qtmultimedia/qtmultimedia.pro /Users/user/QTProjects/qtmultimedia/.qmake.conf .qmake.cache /Users/user/Qt/5.11.3/ios/mkspecs/macx-ios-clang/qmake.conf /Users/user/Qt/5.11.3/ios/mkspecs/features/spec_pre.prf \
        /Users/user/Qt/5.11.3/ios/mkspecs/qdevice.pri \
        /Users/user/Qt/5.11.3/ios/mkspecs/features/device_config.prf \
        /Users/user/Qt/5.11.3/ios/mkspecs/common/unix.conf \
        /Users/user/Qt/5.11.3/ios/mkspecs/common/mac.conf \
        /Users/user/Qt/5.11.3/ios/mkspecs/common/uikit.conf \
        /Users/user/Qt/5.11.3/ios/mkspecs/common/ios.conf \
…
        /Users/user/Qt/5.11.3/ios/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_macextras.pri \
        /Users/user/Qt/5.11.3/ios/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_macextras_private.pri \
        /Users/user/Qt/5.11.3/ios/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_multimedia.pri \
        /Users/user/Qt/5.11.3/ios/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_multimedia_private.pri \
        /Users/user/Qt/5.11.3/ios/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_multimediawidgets.pri \
        /Users/user/Qt/5.11.3/ios/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_multimediawidgets_private.pri \
        /Users/user/Qt/5.11.3/ios/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_network.pri \
        /Users/user/Qt/5.11.3/ios/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_network_private.pri \
        /Users/user/Qt/5.11.3/ios/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_nfc.pri \
        /Users/user/Qt/5.11.3/ios/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_nfc_private.pri \
        /Users/user/Qt/5.11.3/ios/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_opengl.pri \
        /Users/user/Qt/5.11.3/ios/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_opengl_private.pri \
…
        /Users/user/Qt/5.11.3/ios/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_qmltest_private.pri \
        /Users/user/Qt/5.11.3/ios/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_qtmultimediaquicktools_private.pri \
        /Users/user/Qt/5.11.3/ios/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_quick.pri \
        /Users/user/Qt/5.11.3/ios/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_quick_private.pri \
        /Users/user/Qt/5.11.3/ios/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_quickcontrols2.pri \
        /Users/user/Qt/5.11.3/ios/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_quickcontrols2_private.pri \
        /Users/user/Qt/5.11.3/ios/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_quickparticles_private.pri \
        /Users/user/Qt/5.11.3/ios/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_quicktemplates2_private.pri \
        /Users/user/Qt/5.11.3/ios/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_quickwidgets.pri \
        /Users/user/Qt/5.11.3/ios/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_quickwidgets_private.pri \
        /Users/user/Qt/5.11.3/ios/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_scxml.pri \
        /Users/user/Qt/5.11.3/ios/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_scxml_private.pri \
        /Users/user/Qt/5.11.3/ios/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_sensors.pri \
        /Users/user/Qt/5.11.3/ios/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_sensors_private.pri \
        /Users/user/Qt/5.11.3/ios/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_sql.pri \
        /Users/user/Qt/5.11.3/ios/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_sql_private.pri \
        /Users/user/Qt/5.11.3/ios/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_svg.pri \
        /Users/user/Qt/5.11.3/ios/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_svg_private.pri \
…
        /Users/user/Qt/5.11.3/ios/mkspecs/modules/qt_plugin_qtiff.pri \
        /Users/user/Qt/5.11.3/ios/mkspecs/modules/qt_plugin_qtmedia_audioengine.pri \
        /Users/user/Qt/5.11.3/ios/mkspecs/modules/qt_plugin_qtmultimedia_m3u.pri \
        /Users/user/Qt/5.11.3/ios/mkspecs/modules/qt_plugin_qtposition_cl.pri \
        /Users/user/Qt/5.11.3/ios/mkspecs/modules/qt_plugin_qtposition_positionpoll.pri \
        /Users/user/Qt/5.11.3/ios/mkspecs/modules/qt_plugin_qtsensorgestures_plugin.pri \
        /Users/user/Qt/5.11.3/ios/mkspecs/modules/qt_plugin_qtsensorgestures_shakeplugin.pri \
        /Users/user/Qt/5.11.3/ios/mkspecs/modules/qt_plugin_qtsensors_generic.pri \
        /Users/user/Qt/5.11.3/ios/mkspecs/modules/qt_plugin_qtsensors_ios.pri \
        /Users/user/Qt/5.11.3/ios/mkspecs/modules/qt_plugin_qtuiotouchplugin.pri \
        /Users/user/Qt/5.11.3/ios/mkspecs/modules/qt_plugin_qtwebview_darwin.pri \
        /Users/user/Qt/5.11.3/ios/mkspecs/modules/qt_plugin_qwbmp.pri \
        /Users/user/Qt/5.11.3/ios/mkspecs/modules/qt_plugin_qwebp.pri \
        /Users/user/Qt/5.11.3/ios/mkspecs/modules/qt_plugin_scene2d.pri \
        mkspecs/modules-inst/qt_lib_multimedia.pri \
        mkspecs/modules-inst/qt_lib_multimedia_private.pri \
        mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_multimedia.pri \
        mkspecs/modules-inst/qt_lib_multimediawidgets.pri \
        mkspecs/modules-inst/qt_lib_multimediawidgets_private.pri \
        mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_multimediawidgets.pri \
        mkspecs/modules-inst/qt_lib_qtmultimediaquicktools_private.pri \
        mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_qtmultimediaquicktools_private.pri \
        mkspecs/modules-inst/qt_plugin_qavfcamera.pri \
        mkspecs/modules/qt_plugin_qavfcamera.pri \
        mkspecs/modules-inst/qt_plugin_qavfmediaplayer.pri \
        mkspecs/modules/qt_plugin_qavfmediaplayer.pri \
        mkspecs/modules-inst/qt_plugin_qtaudio_coreaudio.pri \
        mkspecs/modules/qt_plugin_qtaudio_coreaudio.pri \
        mkspecs/modules-inst/qt_plugin_qtmedia_audioengine.pri \
        mkspecs/modules/qt_plugin_qtmedia_audioengine.pri \
        mkspecs/modules-inst/qt_plugin_qtmultimedia_m3u.pri \
        mkspecs/modules/qt_plugin_qtmultimedia_m3u.pri \
        /Users/user/Qt/5.11.3/ios/mkspecs/features/qt_functions.prf \
        /Users/user/Qt/5.11.3/ios/mkspecs/features/qt_config.prf \
        /Users/user/Qt/5.11.3/ios/mkspecs/macx-ios-clang/qmake.conf \
        /Users/user/Qt/5.11.3/ios/mkspecs/features/spec_post.prf \
        /Users/user/Qt/5.11.3/ios/mkspecs/qmodule.pri \
        /Users/user/Qt/5.11.3/ios/mkspecs/features/qt_build_config.prf \
        /Users/user/QTProjects/qtmultimedia/.qmake.conf \
        .qmake.cache \
        .qmake.stash \
        /Users/user/Qt/5.11.3/ios/mkspecs/features/exclusive_builds.prf \
        /Users/user/Qt/5.11.3/ios/mkspecs/features/mac/sdk.prf \
        /Users/user/Qt/5.11.3/ios/mkspecs/features/uikit/sdk.prf \
        /Users/user/Qt/5.11.3/ios/mkspecs/features/toolchain.prf \
        /Users/user/Qt/5.11.3/ios/mkspecs/features/mac/toolchain.prf \
        /Users/user/Qt/5.11.3/ios/mkspecs/features/default_pre.prf \
        /Users/user/Qt/5.11.3/ios/mkspecs/features/mac/default_pre.prf \
        /Users/user/Qt/5.11.3/ios/mkspecs/features/uikit/default_pre.prf \
        /Users/user/Qt/5.11.3/ios/mkspecs/features/configure_base.prf \
        config.cache \
        /Users/user/Qt/5.11.3/ios/mkspecs/features/qt_configure.prf \
        /Users/user/Qt/5.11.3/ios/mkspecs/features/qt_parts.prf \
        /Users/user/Qt/5.11.3/ios/mkspecs/features/uikit/qt_parts.prf \
        /Users/user/Qt/5.11.3/ios/mkspecs/features/resolve_config.prf \
…
        /Users/user/Qt/5.11.3/ios/mkspecs/features/mac/asset_catalogs.prf \
        /Users/user/Qt/5.11.3/ios/mkspecs/features/testcase_targets.prf \
        /Users/user/Qt/5.11.3/ios/mkspecs/features/uikit/testcase_targets.prf \
        /Users/user/Qt/5.11.3/ios/mkspecs/features/yacc.prf \
        /Users/user/Qt/5.11.3/ios/mkspecs/features/lex.prf \
        /Users/user/QTProjects/qtmultimedia/qtmultimedia.pro
    $(QMAKE) -o Makefile /Users/user/QTProjects/qtmultimedia/qtmultimedia.pro
/Users/user/Qt/5.11.3/ios/mkspecs/features/spec_pre.prf:
/Users/user/Qt/5.11.3/ios/mkspecs/qdevice.pri:
/Users/user/Qt/5.11.3/ios/mkspecs/features/device_config.prf:
/Users/user/Qt/5.11.3/ios/mkspecs/common/unix.conf:
/Users/user/Qt/5.11.3/ios/mkspecs/common/mac.conf:
/Users/user/Qt/5.11.3/ios/mkspecs/common/uikit.conf:
/Users/user/Qt/5.11.3/ios/mkspecs/common/ios.conf:
/Users/user/Qt/5.11.3/ios/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_multimedia.pri:
/Users/user/Qt/5.11.3/ios/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_multimedia_private.pri:
/Users/user/Qt/5.11.3/ios/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_multimediawidgets.pri:
/Users/user/Qt/5.11.3/ios/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_multimediawidgets_private.pri:
…

/Users/user/Qt/5.11.3/ios/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_quickwidgets_private.pri:
/Users/user/Qt/5.11.3/ios/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_scxml.pri:
/Users/user/Qt/5.11.3/ios/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_scxml_private.pri:
/Users/user/Qt/5.11.3/ios/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_sensors.pri:
/Users/user/Qt/5.11.3/ios/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_sensors_private.pri:
/Users/user/Qt/5.11.3/ios/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_sql.pri:
/Users/user/Qt/5.11.3/ios/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_sql_private.pri:
/Users/user/Qt/5.11.3/ios/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_svg.pri:
/Users/user/Qt/5.11.3/ios/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_svg_private.pri:
…

/Users/user/Qt/5.11.3/ios/mkspecs/modules/qt_plugin_qtiff.pri:
/Users/user/Qt/5.11.3/ios/mkspecs/modules/qt_plugin_qtmedia_audioengine.pri:
/Users/user/Qt/5.11.3/ios/mkspecs/modules/qt_plugin_qtmultimedia_m3u.pri:
…
mkspecs/modules-inst/qt_lib_multimedia.pri:
mkspecs/modules-inst/qt_lib_multimedia_private.pri:
mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_multimedia.pri:
mkspecs/modules-inst/qt_lib_multimediawidgets.pri:
mkspecs/modules-inst/qt_lib_multimediawidgets_private.pri:
mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_multimediawidgets.pri:
mkspecs/modules-inst/qt_lib_qtmultimediaquicktools_private.pri:
mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_qtmultimediaquicktools_private.pri:
mkspecs/modules-inst/qt_plugin_qavfcamera.pri:
mkspecs/modules/qt_plugin_qavfcamera.pri:
mkspecs/modules-inst/qt_plugin_qavfmediaplayer.pri:
mkspecs/modules/qt_plugin_qavfmediaplayer.pri:
mkspecs/modules-inst/qt_plugin_qtaudio_coreaudio.pri:
mkspecs/modules/qt_plugin_qtaudio_coreaudio.pri:
mkspecs/modules-inst/qt_plugin_qtmedia_audioengine.pri:
mkspecs/modules/qt_plugin_qtmedia_audioengine.pri:
mkspecs/modules-inst/qt_plugin_qtmultimedia_m3u.pri:
mkspecs/modules/qt_plugin_qtmultimedia_m3u.pri:
/Users/user/Qt/5.11.3/ios/mkspecs/features/qt_functions.prf:
/Users/user/Qt/5.11.3/ios/mkspecs/features/qt_config.prf:
/Users/user/Qt/5.11.3/ios/mkspecs/macx-ios-clang/qmake.conf:
/Users/user/Qt/5.11.3/ios/mkspecs/features/spec_post.prf:
/Users/user/Qt/5.11.3/ios/mkspecs/qmodule.pri:
/Users/user/Qt/5.11.3/ios/mkspecs/features/qt_build_config.prf:
/Users/user/QTProjects/qtmultimedia/.qmake.conf:
.qmake.cache:
.qmake.stash:
/Users/user/Qt/5.11.3/ios/mkspecs/features/exclusive_builds.prf:
/Users/user/Qt/5.11.3/ios/mkspecs/features/mac/sdk.prf:
/Users/user/Qt/5.11.3/ios/mkspecs/features/uikit/sdk.prf:
/Users/user/Qt/5.11.3/ios/mkspecs/features/toolchain.prf:
/Users/user/Qt/5.11.3/ios/mkspecs/features/mac/toolchain.prf:
/Users/user/Qt/5.11.3/ios/mkspecs/features/default_pre.prf:
/Users/user/Qt/5.11.3/ios/mkspecs/features/mac/default_pre.prf:
/Users/user/Qt/5.11.3/ios/mkspecs/features/uikit/default_pre.prf:
/Users/user/Qt/5.11.3/ios/mkspecs/features/configure_base.prf:
config.cache:
/Users/user/Qt/5.11.3/ios/mkspecs/features/qt_configure.prf:
/Users/user/Qt/5.11.3/ios/mkspecs/features/qt_parts.prf:
/Users/user/Qt/5.11.3/ios/mkspecs/features/uikit/qt_parts.prf:
/Users/user/Qt/5.11.3/ios/mkspecs/features/resolve_config.prf:
/Users/user/Qt/5.11.3/ios/mkspecs/features/uikit/resolve_config.prf:
/Users/user/Qt/5.11.3/ios/mkspecs/features/default_post.prf:
/Users/user/Qt/5.11.3/ios/mkspecs/features/mac/default_post.prf:
/Users/user/Qt/5.11.3/ios/mkspecs/features/uikit/default_post.prf:
/Users/user/Qt/5.11.3/ios/mkspecs/macx-ios-clang/features/default_post.prf:
…
/Users/user/QTProjects/qtmultimedia/qtmultimedia.pro:
qmake: FORCE
    @$(QMAKE) -o Makefile /Users/user/QTProjects/qtmultimedia/qtmultimedia.pro

qmake_all: sub-src-qmake_all sub-examples-qmake_all sub-tests-qmake_all FORCE

make_first: sub-src-make_first  FORCE
all: sub-src-all sub-examples-all sub-tests-all  FORCE
clean: sub-src-clean sub-examples-clean sub-tests-clean  FORCE
distclean: sub-src-distclean sub-examples-distclean sub-tests-distclean alsa-distclean avfoundation-distclean directshow-distclean evr-distclean gpu_vivante-distclean gstreamer-distclean gstreamer_appsrc-distclean gstreamer_encodingprofiles-distclean gstreamer_photography-distclean linux_v4l-distclean mmrenderer-distclean openal-distclean pulseaudio-distclean resourcepolicy-distclean wasapi-distclean wmf-distclean wmsdk-distclean wshellitem-distclean FORCE
    -$(DEL_FILE) Makefile
    -$(DEL_FILE) .qmake.cache config.cache config.log mkspecs/modules/*.pri mkspecs/modules-inst/*.pri .qmake.stash
install_subtargets: sub-src-install_subtargets FORCE
uninstall_subtargets: sub-src-uninstall_subtargets FORCE

alsa-distclean:
    -cd config.tests/alsa && $(MAKE) distclean

avfoundation-distclean:
    -cd config.tests/avfoundation && $(MAKE) distclean

directshow-distclean:
    -cd config.tests/directshow && $(MAKE) distclean

evr-distclean:
    -cd config.tests/evr && $(MAKE) distclean

gpu_vivante-distclean:
    -cd config.tests/gpu_vivante && $(MAKE) distclean

gstreamer-distclean:
    -cd config.tests/gstreamer && $(MAKE) distclean

gstreamer_appsrc-distclean:
    -cd config.tests/gstreamer_appsrc && $(MAKE) distclean

gstreamer_encodingprofiles-distclean:
    -cd config.tests/gstreamer_encodingprofiles && $(MAKE) distclean

gstreamer_photography-distclean:
    -cd config.tests/gstreamer_photography && $(MAKE) distclean

linux_v4l-distclean:
    -cd config.tests/linux_v4l && $(MAKE) distclean

mmrenderer-distclean:
    -cd config.tests/mmrenderer && $(MAKE) distclean

openal-distclean:
    -cd config.tests/openal && $(MAKE) distclean

pulseaudio-distclean:
    -cd config.tests/pulseaudio && $(MAKE) distclean

resourcepolicy-distclean:
    -cd config.tests/resourcepolicy && $(MAKE) distclean

wasapi-distclean:
    -cd config.tests/wasapi && $(MAKE) distclean

wmf-distclean:
    -cd config.tests/wmf && $(MAKE) distclean

wmsdk-distclean:
    -cd config.tests/wmsdk && $(MAKE) distclean

wshellitem-distclean:
    -cd config.tests/wshellitem && $(MAKE) distclean

html_docs:
    $(MAKE) -f $(MAKEFILE) prepare_docs && $(MAKE) -f $(MAKEFILE) generate_docs

docs:
    $(MAKE) -f $(MAKEFILE) html_docs && $(MAKE) -f $(MAKEFILE) qch_docs

sub-src-install_html_docs:
    @test -d src/ || mkdir -p src/
    cd src/ && ( test -e Makefile || $(QMAKE) -o Makefile /Users/user/QTProjects/qtmultimedia/src/src.pro ) && $(MAKE) -f Makefile install_html_docs
install_html_docs: sub-src-install_html_docs

sub-src-uninstall_html_docs:
    @test -d src/ || mkdir -p src/
    cd src/ && ( test -e Makefile || $(QMAKE) -o Makefile /Users/user/QTProjects/qtmultimedia/src/src.pro ) && $(MAKE) -f Makefile uninstall_html_docs
uninstall_html_docs: sub-src-uninstall_html_docs

sub-src-install_qch_docs:
    @test -d src/ || mkdir -p src/
    cd src/ && ( test -e Makefile || $(QMAKE) -o Makefile /Users/user/QTProjects/qtmultimedia/src/src.pro ) && $(MAKE) -f Makefile install_qch_docs
install_qch_docs: sub-src-install_qch_docs

sub-src-uninstall_qch_docs:
    @test -d src/ || mkdir -p src/
    cd src/ && ( test -e Makefile || $(QMAKE) -o Makefile /Users/user/QTProjects/qtmultimedia/src/src.pro ) && $(MAKE) -f Makefile uninstall_qch_docs
uninstall_qch_docs: sub-src-uninstall_qch_docs

sub-src-install_docs:
    @test -d src/ || mkdir -p src/
    cd src/ && ( test -e Makefile || $(QMAKE) -o Makefile /Users/user/QTProjects/qtmultimedia/src/src.pro ) && $(MAKE) -f Makefile install_docs
install_docs: sub-src-install_docs

sub-src-uninstall_docs:
    @test -d src/ || mkdir -p src/
    cd src/ && ( test -e Makefile || $(QMAKE) -o Makefile /Users/user/QTProjects/qtmultimedia/src/src.pro ) && $(MAKE) -f Makefile uninstall_docs
uninstall_docs: sub-src-uninstall_docs

sub-src-qch_docs:
    @test -d src/ || mkdir -p src/
    cd src/ && ( test -e Makefile || $(QMAKE) -o Makefile /Users/user/QTProjects/qtmultimedia/src/src.pro ) && $(MAKE) -f Makefile qch_docs
qch_docs: sub-src-qch_docs

sub-src-prepare_docs:
    @test -d src/ || mkdir -p src/
    cd src/ && ( test -e Makefile || $(QMAKE) -o Makefile /Users/user/QTProjects/qtmultimedia/src/src.pro ) && $(MAKE) -f Makefile prepare_docs
prepare_docs: sub-src-prepare_docs

sub-src-generate_docs:
    @test -d src/ || mkdir -p src/
    cd src/ && ( test -e Makefile || $(QMAKE) -o Makefile /Users/user/QTProjects/qtmultimedia/src/src.pro ) && $(MAKE) -f Makefile generate_docs
generate_docs: sub-src-generate_docs

sub-src-check:
    @test -d src/ || mkdir -p src/
    cd src/ && ( test -e Makefile || $(QMAKE) -o Makefile /Users/user/QTProjects/qtmultimedia/src/src.pro ) && $(MAKE) -f Makefile check
check: sub-src-check

sub-src-benchmark:
    @test -d src/ || mkdir -p src/
    cd src/ && ( test -e Makefile || $(QMAKE) -o Makefile /Users/user/QTProjects/qtmultimedia/src/src.pro ) && $(MAKE) -f Makefile benchmark
benchmark: sub-src-benchmark
install:install_subtargets  FORCE

uninstall: uninstall_subtargets FORCE

FORCE:

dist: distdir FORCE
    (cd `dirname $(DISTDIR)` && $(TAR) $(DISTNAME).tar $(DISTNAME) && $(COMPRESS) $(DISTNAME).tar) && $(MOVE) `dirname $(DISTDIR)`/$(DISTNAME).tar.gz . && $(DEL_FILE) -r $(DISTDIR)

distdir: sub-src-distdir sub-examples-distdir sub-tests-distdir FORCE
    @test -d $(DISTDIR) || mkdir -p $(DISTDIR)
    $(COPY_FILE) --parents /Users/user/QTProjects/qtmultimedia/.qmake.conf /Users/user/QTProjects/qtmultimedia/qtmultimedia.pro $(DISTDIR)/

sub-src-distdir: FORCE
    @test -d src/ || mkdir -p src/
    cd src/ && ( test -e Makefile || $(QMAKE) -o Makefile /Users/user/QTProjects/qtmultimedia/src/src.pro ) && $(MAKE) -e -f Makefile distdir DISTDIR=$(DISTDIR)/src

sub-examples-distdir: FORCE
    @test -d examples/ || mkdir -p examples/
    cd examples/ && ( test -e Makefile || $(QMAKE) -o Makefile /Users/user/QTProjects/qtmultimedia/examples/examples.pro ) && $(MAKE) -e -f Makefile distdir DISTDIR=$(DISTDIR)/examples

sub-tests-distdir: FORCE
    @test -d tests/ || mkdir -p tests/
    cd tests/ && ( test -e Makefile || $(QMAKE) -o Makefile /Users/user/QTProjects/qtmultimedia/tests/tests.pro ) && $(MAKE) -e -f Makefile distdir DISTDIR=$(DISTDIR)/tests
```

What ever I try to do nothing changes, I made sure to check if `Qt creator` uses the right paths, and yes they point to `~user/Qt/5.11.3/ios`, the same one used to run `qmake` which should replace it's `qtmultimedia` with the one I modified.

Is it possible that `Xcode Command Line Tools` does something that affects the build? Since from last time when the building worked normally, xcode has been updated and if I remember correctly they changed some paths for it?

Or is there any other cause for `qtmultimedia` working the same after a custom build?

Also is it possible to check the compiled version for the changes I did (e.g. search for some string/variable I added in the source code inside `~user/Qt/5.11.3/ios` to make sure it actually got replaced with my version)?

In my `qml` file I `import QtMultimedia 5.9` and create a simple `MediaPlayer` and `VideoOutput` to play a url.

Comment: You can check the last modified timestamp of the created files. It should be newer than any other files in your Qt installation. Also delete the build folder of your test application and built it again, as on iOs even plugins are static

Comment: I did check the creation date, and it does change for some files related to `qtmultimedia` (inside `/Users/user/Qt/5.11.3/ios/qml/QtMultimedia` and `/Users/user/Qt/5.11.3/ios/include/QtMultimedia`) I also manually delete the applications build folder every time, still no success.

Comment: Try running `make INSTALL_ROOT=/tmp/insttest install` and check the contents of that directory. Does it (in some subdirectory) contain the plugin you are trying to modifiy? If not, you have to adjust the build configuration

Comment: I went with it after `make`, and it created few folders, all of them contain something related to QtMultimedia (at least based on file names), I guess with this it should mean it's working right?

Comment: The one thing you are looking for is the correct plugin - it should be in `<prefix>/plugins/mediaservice` and named something like `qavfmediaplayer.dylib` This is the modified plugin you created and the only thing that truely changed

Comment: These are the only mediaplayer files in `<prefix>/plugins/mediaservice`

   `-rw-r--r--  1 user  wheel   1.2M Jan  3 13:27 libqavfmediaplayer.a`
    `-rw-r--r--  1 user  wheel   1.7K Jan  3 13:27 libqavfmediaplayer.prl`
    `-rw-r--r--  1 user  wheel    17M Jan  3 13:27 libqavfmediaplayer_debug.a`
   ` -rw-r--r--  1 user  wheel   1.8K Jan  3 13:27 libqavfmediaplayer_debug.prl`

should there be a `.dylib` too?

Comment: Let's continue this in the [Chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186114/discussion-between-wtferror-and-felix)